# Can I add the default servlet parameters to the org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg file ? If yes how?

Tags: servlets, jetty, vaadin, embedded-jetty, apache-karaf

I have an embedded jetty in karaf in my application. I need to add the **default servlet** parameter **accept-ranges** as **bytes**. Can I add into the ***org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg*** file. If yes than what should be the property? I referred this [link](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/Configuration) but couldn't find the valid property name and its value. If not what is the other alternative approach to add the default servlet parameters into the embedded jetty of karaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pax Web is a mediation layer on top of a variety of Serlvet Containers, like Jetty, Tomcat and Undertow to help people use those within an OSGi environment, the default servlet isn't one provided by the underlying Serlvet Container but of PaxWeb itself. So it's a bit tricky to add those parameters to the ResourceServlet.
It's usually better to define your own Serlet which listenes on "/"